# When I switch my php contact form from get to post it doesn't work

Tags: php, html, forms, post, media-queries

Here is my contact form and you can see it here at [benlevywebdesign.com](http://benlevywebdesign.com) at the bottom of the page.

```
<form id="form1" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" enctype="text/plain" method="get">    

        <fieldset>
            <p class="form">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" />
            </p>
            <p class="form">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="30" />
            </p>
            <p class="form">
                <label for="web">Website</label>
                <input type="text" name="web" id="web" size="30" />
            </p>            
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>                                                                          
            <p class="form">
                <label for="message">Message</label>
                <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
            </p>                                
        </fieldset>                 

        <p class="submit"><button name="submit" type="submit">Send</button></p>

    </form>`
```

and here is the php code I am trying to switch from get to post. I don't know that much php

```
<?php
        if(isset($_GET['submit'])){

            $to = "benlevygraphics@gmail.com";
            $headers = "From: " . $_GET['email'];
            $subject = "Ben, you have been contacted by...";
            $body = "Name: " . $_GET['name'] . "\nEmail: " . $_GET['email'] . "\nWebsite: " . $_GET['web'] . "\nMessage: " . $_GET['message'];
            if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)){
                echo("<p>Your message has been sent!</p>");
            }
            else{
               echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
            }
       }

?>
```

Comment: It'd be more helpful to post the `POST` version of the code that you say isn't working.

Comment: the `POST` version would be the same as the get version. I don't know anything about php right now

Comment: `enctype="text/plain"`?! How is form data supposed to be encoded as *plain* text? (The disturbing thing is that HTML 5 appears to allow it)

Comment: Well for a start all your `$_GET[]` variables need to be changed to `$_POST[]` ones and the form needs `method="post"` instead.

Comment: I did that and nothing worked? Is there something else I am missing?

Comment: Are you sure there's no div overlapping the form at small resolution for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, get rid of your `enctype` attribute. You are setting it to `text/plain` about which the specification says:

> Payloads using the text/plain format are intended to be human readable. They are not reliably interpretable by computer

Second, set `method` to `"POST"`

Third, in the PHP use `$_POST` not `$_GET`

Fourth, don't output content from `$_POST/GET/SERVER/ETC` into an HTML document without first encoding it with [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars). Otherwise you have a huge XSS security vulnerability.

Comment: Hold on, one step at a time as I am new to php

Comment: That *is* one step at a time. They are clearly enumerated. Keeping steps 2 and 3 secret until you tried step 1 and then complained that it didn't work seems silly.

Comment: ok that worked! Now what is the last step you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
<p class="submit"><button name="submit" type="submit">Send</button></p>
```

By

```
<p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send" /></p>
```

Comment: can you explain this as I know nothing about php

Comment: To send an HTML form must perform the action "submit". <button> Label itself does not run this action when pressed. For this you use the label <input type="submit" /> or javascript.

Comment: Actually, `<button type="submit">` works just as good as a regular `<input type="submit">` . What is the `<submit>` tag, btw?

Comment: Another recommendation is that you would send by POST (instead of sending the data via GET) because it is safer. I recommend you read an HTML and a PHP.

Comment: @benlevywebdesign Just edit the response, as it had an error.

Comment: @Lobo — a `<button>` element is a submit button by default, and even broken browsers will treat it as such when it has the explicit `type="submit"`.